# Render Transparency in edit mode

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

I am doing some modeling with blue prints. I would like to see the blue prints through my mesh. However when I switch to edit mode the transparency is no longer rendered. How can I enable transparency in edit mode? Or is the another way I can see my blue prints through the mesh?

[image]

I am using blender internal.

Comment: Did you tried with "Texture" viewport shading, while in "GLSL" shading mode ?

Comment: @Polosson that's working for me. Feel free to post an answer

Comment: If you are using background images, you can set the image to appear in from of your model and reduce the opacity (of the image).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure you choose `GLSL` shading mode in the properties panel of the 3D view (shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Then, you can switch the viewport shading method to `Texture` in the bottom menu:

[image]

Then, your object will appear transparent (if you set up the material correctly ;) even in edit mode.

Comment: What about Cycles?

Answer (score 0):

In the `3D View` panel, I've selected `Wireframe` so I would get semi-transparent effect, so I could see where are the inner parts of my model.[image: Semi-transparence]